# How to concatenate nested lists together into a new nested list using a loop?

Tags: python

I can't seem to figure out how to do this... I have an example of what I want the outcome to be, but I can't figure out how to do it with a loop.

```
celts = [["Bass", 1,2,3],
         ["Bradley", 7,8,9]]

celts2 = [["Bass", 4,5,6],
          ["Bradley", 1,2,3]]

celts3 = [["Bass", 8, 5, 2],
          ["Bradely", 7,4,1]]

new = celts[0] + celts2[0] + celts3[0], celts[1] + celts2[1] + celts3[1],

print new
```

Result is:

```
(['Bass', 1, 2, 3, 'Bass', 4, 5, 6, 'Bass', 8, 5, 2], ['Bradley', 7, 8, 9, 'Bradley', 1, 2, 3, 'Bradely', 7, 4, 1])
```

Comment: you could use list(new) to convert a tuple into a list

Comment: What is the loop in question, here? Are there going to be multiple top-level lists (`celts4`, `celts5`...), or is each of those three lists going to have more elements?

Comment: @Dolda2000 both actually, there are going to be more top level lists and also more elements in each. This is just a quick example of a way to get the results I want, but I know there has to be a better way to code this.... by loops.

Comment: Why not just put the celt lists into their own list such as: ```[[["Bass", 1,2,3], ["Bradley", 7,8,9]],  [["Bass", 4,5,6], ["Bradley", 1,2,3]], [["Bass", 8, 5, 2],
["Bradely", 7,4,1]]]```?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a list comprehension (which *is* a type of loop):

```
celts = [["Bass", 1,2,3],
         ["Bradley", 7,8,9]]
celts2 = [["Bass", 4,5,6],
          ["Bradley", 1,2,3]]   
celts3 = [["Bass", 8, 5, 2],
          ["Bradely", 7,4,1]]

new = [celts[i] + celts2[i] + celts3[i] for i in range(len(celts))]

>>> print new
[['Bass', 1, 2, 3, 'Bass', 4, 5, 6, 'Bass', 8, 5, 2], ['Bradley', 7, 8, 9, 'Bradley', 1, 2, 3, 'Bradely', 7, 4, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you intend:

```
allcelts = [[["Bass", 1,2,3],
             ["Bradley", 7,8,9]],

            [["Bass", 4,5,6],
             ["Bradley", 1,2,3]],

            [["Bass", 8, 5, 2],
             ["Bradely", 7,4,1]]]

new = []
for i in range(len(allcelts[0])):
    element = []
    for celts in allcelts:
        element.extend(celts[i])
    new.append(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

use , separate element will produce a tuple, if you want a list, you can encompass with []

`new = [celts[0] + celts2[0] + celts3[0], celts[1] + celts2[1] + celts3[1],]`

Comment: Yup, thanks for that input, but not quite my question.